# From what Mysql database changed to the current one?

Tags: mysql

Mysql says no database selected when i type 'show tables;', but when I select a database it says 'Database changed'. From what did it change to the one i selected?

Comment: Server means `Database changed from nothing to $database` in this case.

Comment: Hi @user1094156, we have trouble to understand your question. Could you please add more information. Which OS do you use, what application targets your question. Please edit your question and add as much info as you can.

Comment: @Akina, without the `$` that might just add confusion, something like _"The server message means that it changed from nothing to the database you selected"_ indeed sounds like the answer to me. Care to post it as an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: `$` marks that "database" is not a word but a placeholder where the database name specified in the command is placed.

Answer (score 0):

While telling "Database changed" server means only one - it executes your command successfully, and current database is one you have specified in the command. I.e. it is equal to

> Database changed from "previous database" to "specified database"

If previous database was not defined then this server message means

> Database changed from "none" to "specified database"